# In Laravel, how do I destroy a dispatchable object after it has been dispatched to a job?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel how do I remove from memory a Dispatchable object after it has been constructed and serialized to the jobs table?

I'm sending a long list of large email messages, and my ProcessEmail class (it implements ShouldQueue and uses Dispatchable) has a private field that stores the body of the email.  Now this object will get serialized and saved to the jobs table in the database, and I don't mind that table having lots of data in it.  But while I'm looping through the long list of users to send the emails to, these ProcessEmail objects hang around in memory and use up all the memory on the server.  I would like to unset() the object after it gets written to the database, so it will stop taking up RAM.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

I'm using Laravel 9.

Edit: After digger deeper, it might not be the ProcessEmail object itself taking memory.  There could be some other code that is listening for changes and logging or something.  I finally got this working with less RAM by throwing the email message into a table using DB::connection()->getPdo() instead of using Eloquent, probably so no other code can listen and log anything.

Comment: Show us your loop code. You may be able to use `chunk()` so things happen in a closure, which would mean each invocation can be garbage collected before the next iteration.

Comment: If you just do `ProcessEmail::dispatch(...)` this should result in the job to be dispathched and the instance to be garbage collected relatively quickly (in fact the actual queuing happens on the `__destruct` function of the pending job object) so you may be doing something that keeps a reference of the result of `dispatch`